Why am I seeing Index error in this Python script?
#ResidueNoInEachProtein,Residue,TrueLabel,Feature1,Feature2,Feature3,Feature4,Feature5,Feature6,Feature7,Feature8,Feature9
   0 GLN C   0.000   0.000   0.000 1 1 1 1  1 0
   1 THR E   7.057  10.394   0.000 1 1 1 1  1 0
   2 VAL E   6.710   9.449  13.140 0 0 0 0  1 0
   3 PRO E   6.552   9.752  12.974 0 0 0 0  0 0
   4 SER C   6.544   7.584  11.239 0 0 0 0  0 0
   5 SER C   5.407   5.140   5.159 0 0 0 0  0 0
   6 ASP C   5.485   7.378   5.152 0 0 0 0  0 0
   7 GLY C   5.723   9.048   9.571 0 0 0 1  1 0
   8 THR C   6.347   9.102  10.812 0 0 0 2  2 0
   9 PRO E   6.219   9.620  12.486 0 1 1 3  4 0
  10 ILE E   6.412   9.721  12.781 0 0 0 3  4 0
  11 ALA E   6.603  10.294  13.140 0 1 1 2  3 0
  12 PHE E   7.219  10.586  13.126 0 0 0 2  2 0
  13 GLU E   6.939  10.295  13.972 0 0 0 0  1 0
  14 ARG E   6.814  10.472  13.764 0 0 0 0  0 0
  15 SER E   7.061   9.189  12.947 0 0 0 0  0 0
  16 GLY E   6.872   9.856  11.521 0 0 0 0  0 0
  17 SER C   6.988   9.388  11.337 0 0 0 0  0 0
  18 GLY C   6.903   7.889   9.055 0 0 0 0  0 0


import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier

# Load the data from full.regular.txt
data = pd.read_csv('full.regular.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

# Verify the data structure
print("Data preview:")
print(data.head())
print("\nData columns:")
print(data.columns)

# Assuming columns are correctly read, let’s inspect their index positions
print("\nColumn positions and data types:")
print(data.dtypes)

# Extract the true label and features based on given specifications
# Column 3 is index 2 and columns 4 to 12 are index 3 to 11
try:
    y = data.iloc[:, 2]
    X = data.iloc[:, 3:11]
except IndexError as e:
    print(f"IndexError: {e}")
    print("The dataset does not have the expected number of columns.")
    print("Please check the dataset and ensure it matches the expected format.")

# Verify the shapes of X and y if the extraction was successful
if 'X' in locals() and 'y' in locals():
    print("\nFeatures shape:", X.shape)
    print("Labels shape:", y.shape)

    # Split the data into training and testing sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    # Initialize and run LazyClassifier
    clf = LazyClassifier(verbose=0, ignore_warnings=True, custom_metric=None)
    train, test = clf.fit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

    # Display the results
    print("\nTraining set evaluation:")
    print(train)
    print("\nTest set evaluation:")
    print(test)

Output:
Data preview:
                                    #ResidueNoInEachProtein,Residue,TrueLabel,Feature1,Feature2,Feature3,Feature4,Feature5,Feature6,Feature7,Feature8,Feature9
0 GLN C 0.00 0.00  0.00  1 1 1 1 1                                                  0                                                                         
1 THR E 7.06 10.39 0.00  1 1 1 1 1                                                  0                                                                         
2 VAL E 6.71 9.45  13.14 0 0 0 0 1                                                  0                                                                         
3 PRO E 6.55 9.75  12.97 0 0 0 0 0                                                  0                                                                         
4 SER C 6.54 7.58  11.24 0 0 0 0 0                                                  0                                                                         

Data columns:
Index(['#ResidueNoInEachProtein,Residue,TrueLabel,Feature1,Feature2,Feature3,Feature4,Feature5,Feature6,Feature7,Feature8,Feature9'], dtype='object')

Column positions and data types:
#ResidueNoInEachProtein,Residue,TrueLabel,Feature1,Feature2,Feature3,Feature4,Feature5,Feature6,Feature7,Feature8,Feature9    int64
dtype: object
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
The dataset does not have the expected number of columns.
Please check the dataset and ensure it matches the expected format.

Features shape: (1079134, 8)
Labels shape: (1079134,)
100%|██████████| 29/29 [00:00<00:00, 3085.30it/s]

Training set evaluation:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Accuracy, Balanced Accuracy, ROC AUC, F1 Score, Time Taken]
Index: []

Test set evaluation:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Accuracy, Balanced Accuracy, ROC AUC, F1 Score, Time Taken]
Index: []


I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.
Why am I seeing Index error in this Python script?

I'm not familiar with how this works, but your Index(['...']) contents is just one string and not a list of strings.

That error tells you exactly what the issue is, your data doesn't have the expected number of columns.  When the code tries to filter the data to get your x data using X = data.iloc[:, 3:11] it can't as there isn't a column 11.  I only count 10 in your data preview, and python starts counting from 0, so there are 2 columns missing?

theres something funky with your txt file. You'll see its only seeing it as 8 columns when you print out the .shape. Mind sharing that file so I can debug??

Also, looking at the print statement of the dataframe, I see only 11 columns. That first column is the index and would not be part of the iloc columns slicing If you want that to actually be a column, you'd need to indicate that.. So perhaps you want to change to y = data.iloc[:, 1] and X = data.iloc[:, 2:10] Lastly, do you want to include that last column? when slicing, it does not include the last value index. so again, do you really want X = data.iloc[:, 2:] ? Hard to answer your question w/out seeing that txt file & knowing which column is your target and which you want for features.

Your delimiter does not recognize columns as expected, so you may explicitly define column names as:
column_names = [
    'ResidueNoInEachProtein', 'Residue', 'TrueLabel', 'Feature1', 'Feature2',
    'Feature3', 'Feature4', 'Feature5', 'Feature6', 'Feature7', 'Feature8', 'Feature9'
]

# Load the data from full.regular.txt with the specified delimiter and column names
data = pd.read_csv('full.regular.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=column_names, skiprows=1)


This should help..
